# Broken function even though it appears to be correct

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I've been testing my app today and somehow a function broke after I've done a completely unrelated change, and most importantly I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Here it is:

```
public static int componentStrId(String string)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < GameMain.ComponentNames.length; i++)
        {
            Gdx.app.log("GameCoordinator", "componentStrId index: " + i);
            if(string == GameMain.ComponentNames[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Before you ask, yes, the string I feed it is present in the array I search from, and yet the function returns -1. It just cycles pointlessly through the array.

I've got the feeling that Eclipse freaked out, although maybe I'm just blind and can't see an obvious mistake... So what is it, the former or the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this ...

```
if(string == GameMain.ComponentNames[i])
```

Use this ...

```
if(string.equals(GameMain.ComponentNames[i]))
```

Comment: Great to hear. The == comparison determines whether the objects are the exact same instance, whereas equals compares their value (actually compares their hashcode/equals method). That's why ("abc" == new String("abc")) is false, but ("abc".equals(new String("abc"))) is true.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide

```
GameMain.ComponentNames[3]
```

as parameter it would return `3`.

If you construct a String separately it would always return -1, as `==` would return true only if both references point at the same object.